# Calculation of efficiency of a heat engine

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

The efficiency of any heat engine doing work $W = |Q_{in}| - |Q_{out}|$ is given by:

$N = |W|/|Q_{in}|$

The reasoning for this given in my textbook is along the lines of:

> The purpose of any heat engine is to transform as much of the
> extracted energy into work as possible. We measure its success in
> doing so by its thermal efficiency defined as the work the engine does
> per cycle (energy we get) divided by energy the it absorbs per heat
> cycle (energy we pay for).

I'm taking the example of a Carnot engine.

During the process of isothermal compression and adiabatic compression, the surrounding does work on the system, i.e the substance of our engine gains energy from the surrounding in the form of work. Why do we not count this energy in as a part of the energy we supply into the system? In the formula of efficiency, why do we not take "Energy we pay for" as heat energy supplied during isothermal expansion + work done on substance during compression?

Comment: The work W is the **net** work done by the system. It already incorporates (by subtraction) any work done **on** the system. Please consider editing your question to indicate where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motivation comes from the way we run the heat engine: we pay for the heat at the boiler ($|Q_\text{in}|$) and we get paid for the work we produce ($|W|$). The efficiency essentially measures the profit we make: what percentage of the purchased energy is converted into work.

You are correct that in some portions of the cycle we add energy in the form of work. In a power plant, for example, we need a pump to compress the water that goes in the boiler.  The complete energy balance is
$$|Q_\text{in}|-|Q_\text{out}| =|W_\text{out}| - |W_\text{in}|$$
The idea here is that the cost for this work is covered by the (a lot more) work we get in the turbine. For this reason we combine $|W_\text{out}| - |W_\text{in}|$ into a single term which we call *net* amout of work produced.

To sum it up, the "efficiency" of the heat engine is an anthopocentric concept based on the notion that the user ("us") would rather have energy in the form of work instead of heat.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we not count this energy in as a part of the energy we supply
> into the system? In the formula of efficiency, why do we not take
> "Energy we pay for" as heat energy supplied during isothermal
> expansion + work done on substance during compression?

The short answer is energy in due to compression work is part of $W$ in the efficiency equation since $W$ is the *net work* done by the cycle, which includes expansion and compression work.

Since the adiabatic expansion and compression work in the Carnot Cycle cancel each other, the net work done is the positive work of the isothermal expansion, which is energy out, plus the negative work done by the isothermal compression, which is energy in.

Hope this helps.